# Creating PACMAN Background map on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, colormap, pacman

So I am currently in the process of making PACMAN on MATLAB, but cannot seem to  figure out how to start the generation of the map on the main figure. I can either use a .png file that has the background in class uint8 RGB, but this case does not allow me to register the walls that impede the path of PACMAN and the ghosts. Another method I believe would work would be to just create the map myself with 0's,1's, and 2's which represent the location of black empty pixels, blue walls(filled), and dots(yellow), respectively. However, in trying to do latter method, I am having an issue assigning a color to each specific index of the 300 x 300 matrix in a switch-case-otherwise method. Any suggestions about how to  continue? Any response would be greatly appreciate and below is the  sample code that I have attempted to create so far:

```
function level = LevelOne()
% the functionality of this function is to generate the walls that
% PACMAN and the ghosts cannot cross

% Create color map
color = [255 75 75; % red 1
153 0 0; % dark red 2
255 255 153; % light yellow 3
255 102 178; % pink 4
0 0 0; % black 5
0 255 255; % light blue 6
0 0 255; % blue 7
255 255 153; % light yellow 8
192 192 192; % silver 9
255 255 255]/255; % white 10

%create general map area
level = zeros(300);


%create location of filled in walls(represented by 1's)
level(18:38,37:70) = 1;
level(65:75,37:70) = 1;
level(300-18:300-38,300-37:300-70) = 1;
level(300-65:300-75,300-37:300-70) = 1;


[x,y] = size(level);

axis([0 x 0 y])
for ii = 1:x
    for jj = 1:y
        switch level(ii,jj)
            case 1 %represents a blue wall

            case 0 %represents an empty black space for PACMAN & Ghosts to move through

            case 2 %represents the location of the fruit

            case 3 %represents the location 

            otherwise

        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you can load the matrix data from an image (which can easily be drawn in a photo-editing application) into an new matrix, getting the best of both worlds.
Something like this:

```
image = imread('map.png');
grayLevel = image(row, column); ' Get the pixel like that if it is grayscale image.
rgbColor = impixel(image, column, row); ' Get the pixel like that if it is colorful image.
```

Looping though the image data and copying it into a matrix (maybe converting colors into your 0/1/2/3 values in the meanwhile) is the next step.

I have not tested this at all, but here is my try:

```
level = zeros(300);
[x,y] = size(level);

% Copy from image.
for ii = 1:x
    for jj = 1:y
        level(ii,jj) = image(ii, jj); % Here maybe convert blue to 1, etc yourself. I only copy data here.
    end
end

% Render it.
axis([0 x 0 y])
for ii = 1:x
    for jj = 1:y
        switch level(ii,jj)
            case 1 %represents a blue wall
                rectangle('Position',[ii, jj, 1, 1],'FaceColor',[0 0 .5],'EdgeColor','b', 'LineWidth', 1)
            case 0 %represents an empty black space for PACMAN & Ghosts to move through
                rectangle('Position',[ii, jj, 1, 1],'FaceColor',[0 0 0],'EdgeColor','b', 'LineWidth', 1)

            case 2 %represents the location of the fruit

            case 3 %represents the location 

            otherwise

        end
    end
end
```

And this should draw the rectangle, if that's what you are asking:

```
rectangle('Position',[1,2,5,10],'FaceColor',[0 0 .5],'EdgeColor','b', 'LineWidth', 1)
```

Generally, try Google searching, since this will give you more info.
Now, moving things and removing things from the plot is another issue...

Some links:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/151779-how-to-extract-the-value-pixel-valu-from-image